# Allow today's date and future date by comparing with today's date in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, validation

I have a entry form in which I can allow today's date and future date but can't allow yesterday and previous days. I need to do this validation using java-script on client side.

```
var futuredate = new Date($("#Deadline").val());
var today = new Date();
```

This gives me date with time. `Mon Nov 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
I want only date to compare as when user enters today's date 
entered date is : `Fri Apr 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
current date from new Date():`Fri Apr 05 2013 16:53:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

I tried using `sethours()` it worked fine for current month, but as it converts date in number it creates problem when date entered is of previous or any before month. 
for example: the date entered date is `23/3/2013` and today is `5/4/2013` it considers the entered date as valid.

```
var futuredate = new Date($("#Deadline").val()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
if (futuredate >= today) {
   alert("Valid");
}
else if (futuredate < today) {
   alert("InValid");
}
```

Comment: There are loads of answers on comparing dates have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170054/compare-two-dates-with-javascript

Comment: i want to compare date without time... I already surfed on stack for answers... they didn't solved my problems...

Comment: @bluesky what will be your input date, just provide an example.

Comment: @bluesky i've added an answer, please give it a go

Comment: This has nothing to do with the [tag:jquery-validate] plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging your questions.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, it uses a little function to parse your datestring into a date object before using `setHours()`. This will work if your string is in format dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy.

```
var futuredate = parseDate(input).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
if (futuredate >= today) {
   alert("Valid");
}
else if (futuredate < today) {
   alert("InValid");
}

//function to return a date object from the date string passed to it
function parseDate(input) {
    var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
    return new Date(parts[2], (parts[1]-1), parts[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just split the date and set the date function concept .using this way we can easily compare the the date

```
 var a =futuredate.split('/');
 var b =today.split('/');
 var date1 = new Date(a[2],a[1],a[0]);
 var date2 = new Date(b[2],b[1],b[0]);

if (date1 >= date2) {
   alert("Valid");
}
else if (date1 < date2) {
   alert("InValid");
}
```