# Comparing date time using javasctipt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to compare two dates using javascript,The datetime format is given below.Here i want to check date1 > date2.How can i achive this in javascript.

```
 var date1='2014-03-25 07:30 AM';
 var date2='2014-03-25 04:30 PM';
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170054/compare-two-dates-with-javascript#answer-11170062

Comment: You're going to need to format these date strings differently before you can instantiate new Date objects that work cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getTime`:

```
 if ((new Date(date1).getTime()) > ( new Date(date2).getTime())){
 }
```

Comment: if i do this alert(new Date(date1).getTime()) i am getting NaN

Comment: That can only happen if `date1` is not what you claim it to be. Can you do `alert(date1)`?

Comment: the date parsing performed by `new Date` is culture specific on your machine unless the date is in ISO format. If you need to process such a date I recommend looking at moment js parsing capabilities : http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

Answer (score 0):

Like this -

```
if((new Date(date1).getTime()) > (new Date(date2).getTime())){
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
if (new Date(date1) > new Date(date2))
```

Comment: I have test it, it is working well. i also sending you the scenario in which i have performed testing.                           function func() {
        var date1 = '2014-03-25 07:30 AM';
        var date2 = '2014-03-25 04:30 PM';

        if (new Date(date1) > new Date(date2)) {

            alert('date1 ' + date1);
            alert('date2 ' + date2);
        }
        else if (new Date(date1) < new Date(date2)) {
            alert('else date1 ' + date1);
            alert('else date2 ' + date2);
        }
    }

Comment: i dont know why if i simply do alert(new Date(date1)); i am getting invalid date

Comment: can u pls create a fiddle?

Comment: can u pls check it in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    var date1 = '2014-03-25 07:30 AM';
    var date2 = '2014-03-25 04:30 PM';
    console.log((new Date(date1)) >= (new Date(date2)));
```

EDIT:
Op correctly pointed out that the code above does not work (in FireFox, for example, but it works in Chrome). I have read that

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

are valid instantiations for Date [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).

However, the date strings used for date1 and date2 in the example are not valid, therefore not supported in all browsers.

Instead of '2014-03-25 07:30 AM' (which is invalid) you should do one of the following:

- convert your input into milliseconds
- convert your input into date string, like "October 13, 1975 11:13:00"
- calculate the year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds, then pass them to the instantiation