# Sorting String Date Array in ascending and Descending Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Below piece of code:

```
var dateArr = new Array();
dateArr[0] = "11-12-2012";
dateArr[1] = "9-12-2014";
dateArr[2] = "11-12-2012";
dateArr[3] = "9-12-2011";
```

Have to sort the above String Date array in ascending and Descending Order. Please AnyOne give me some suggestions with examples for resolving the same.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Loop over the elements, convert each to a date object and then [sort them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170054/compare-two-dates-with-javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try-

```
var arr = [];
for(var i =0; i<dateArr.length; i++)
{
    date1 = dateArr[i].split("-");
    if(date1[0]<10){date1[0]='0'+date1[0]} 
    if(date1[1]<10){date1[1]='0'+date1[1]} 
    arr.push(new Date(date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0]));
}

arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});  //asc
console.log(formatDateArr(arr));

arr.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});  //desc
console.log(formatDateArr(arr));

function formatDateArr(arr)
{
    formatedArr = [];
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
        var curr_date = arr[i].getDate();
        var curr_month = arr[i].getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
        var curr_year = arr[i].getFullYear();
        formatedArr.push(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
    }
    return formatedArr;
}
```

`arr` will be the sorted date array.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmHeL/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was what i was looking for.

But when i run them on Chrome it was working fine. But when run the same code in Mozilla it was showing the following result :

["NaN-NaN-NaN", "NaN-NaN-NaN", "NaN-NaN-NaN", "NaN-NaN-NaN"]

Can you please help me to sort it Out

Comment: Yes, actually firefox dont creates dates with format DD-MM-YYYY, so we have to first format it a bit before converting it to a date object. I've edited the fiddle link and answer, pl check!

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, but the answer would look like this:

```
dateArr.sort(function(d1,d2) {
    var year1 = d1.substr(6,4);
    var year2 = d2.substr(6,4);
    if (year1 < year2) return -1;
    if (year1 > year2) return 1;

    var month1 = d1.substr(3,2);
    var month2 = d2.substr(3,2);
    if (month1 < month2) return -1;
    if (month1 > month2) return 1;

    if (d1 < d2) return -1;
    if (d1 > d2) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

I can't remember if the -1 or 1 means ascending or descending, so they might need to be swapped around.

Edit: Hang on, this won't work, because some of the dates don't have exactly 10 characters. So you'll have to do a character search (the "indexOf()" method) for the "-" characters, and use those indexes in the .substr method instead of a blind 6,4 or 3,2

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to map the timestamps to dates then sort those:

```js
// Array of dates in d/m/y format
let data = ['11-12-2012', '9-12-2014', '11-12-2012', '9-12-2011'];

// Map strings to Date objects
let dates = data.map(s => {
  let [d, m, y] = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(y, m-1, d);
});

// Sort
dates.sort((a, b) => a - b);

// Show sorted array
dates.forEach(d => console.log(d.toDateString()))
```

Another approach is to map the strings to sortable timestamps, e.g. in ISO 8601 format:

```js
// Array of dates in d/m/y format
let data = ['11-12-2012', '9-12-2014', '11-12-2012', '9-12-2011'];

// Map strings to ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD
let dates = data.map(s => {
  let [d, m, y] = s.split(/\D/);
  return `${y}-${m.padStart(2,'0')}-${d.padStart(2,'0')}`;
});

// Sort - no special sort function required
dates.sort();

// Show sorted array
console.log(dates);
```

Format YYYYMMDD could also be used, but I think YYYY-MM-DD may be useful for other processes.

Lastly, if the intention is to just sort the original array, then the transformation can be undertaken in a sort function, but it's less efficient as each value may be transformed multiple times during the sort, e.g.

```js
// Array of dates in d/m/y format
let data = ['11-12-2012', '9-12-2014', '11-12-2012', '9-12-2011'];

// Use a sort function that sorts the original array
data.sort((a, b) => {
  let p = s => {
    let [d, m, y] = s.split(/\D/);
    return new Date(y, m-1, d);
  };
  return p(a) - p(b);
});

// Show sorted array
console.log(data);
```

The same approach could also be taken using the reformatted string method.