# Change background color of a div according to time

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs

I am trying to create a schedule. According to the current time the `div` `background-color` will change.

Working of the schedule
1) When current time exceeded appointment time add `.dngr` `class` to the `div`
2) When 1 hour is remaining for the interview add `.ready` `class` to the `div`

I am using `PHP` to create the page dynamically. `Bootstrap 3` for the `UI` and `moment.js` for the clock

PHP code

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <?php echo $name;?> <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $u_id;?>" class="pull-right btn btn-primary view" data-placement="top" title="Click to view Resume"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i></a>
        <hr class="no-margin-top-bottom">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i> <?php echo $phone; ?>
        <br/><span class="interviewtime" data-time="<?php echo date('YmdHis', strtotime($schedule));?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> <?php echo date('F jS Y, h:i a', strtotime($schedule)); ?> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code will just display `name` , `phonenumber` and `appointment time`. 
**Note.!!** The above code will be placed inside a loop. There will be multiple `appointments` at a given time i have kept `LIMIT 20`

JQuery code

```
var repeater;

function showcurrenttime()
{
    $('.crnttym').text(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
    repeater = setTimeout(showcurrenttime, 500);

    if ($('.interviewtime').data('time') < moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss'))
    {
        $(this).parent().addClass('dngr');
    }       
}
showcurrenttime();
```

The above code will give the current time. The `if()` condition is a failed attempt to add `.dngr class` to a scheduled appointment, where the current time exceeds the appointment time.

CSS

```
.dngr{background-color: #D9534F;border-color: #D43F3A;color: white}
.ready{background-color: #128666;color: white}
```

**My Problem here is i cannot get the div to change background-color, and also the 2nd point of the working of schedule.All this should be done using javascript**

Comment: Will the `ready` and `dngr` class be applied to the same element at the same time? If so, you need to place the `.dngr` styles later in the CSS file, after `.ready`

Comment: Comparing `$('.interviewtime').data('time') < moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')` seems like the source of the problem. What values, exactly, are you comparing here?

Comment: No No, only a fool will do that hahha. There will be applied to a div on different time. As i have mentioned in the working of the schedule @Blazemonger

Comment: @Blazemonger yes that is the problem the value i get from both is 20140409191900 which is date and time without hyphen and colon

Comment: Look into storing both date strings in [ISO 8601 format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript), then convert them into `Date` objects for true comparison.

Comment: @Blazemonger i try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question the problem was actually the selector. Thanks to @Blazemonger i found a way to select the right div

JQuery Code

```
var repeater;

function showcurrenttime()
{
    $('.crnttym').text(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
    $('.interviewtime').each(function (i, el)
    {
        if ($(this).data('time') < moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss'))
        {
            $(this).parent().addClass('dngr');
        };
        if ($(this).data('time') > moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss') && $(this).data('time') < moment().add('h',1).format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss'))
        {
            $(this).parent().addClass('ready');
        };
    });
    repeater = setTimeout(showcurrenttime, 500);
}
showcurrenttime();
```

I am answering my own question as i manage to solve it with some help and others can refer to this as well

Answer (score 1):

If you're comparing two dates, then compare them *as* dates, not as strings. (You *can* compare them as strings, but formatting can be tricky and, well, what's a `Date` object for if nobody uses it?)

[Output the date in PHP using ISO 8601 format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
data-time="<?php echo date('c', strtotime($schedule));?>
```

Then convert it to a JavaScript `Date` object:

```
var idate = new Date($('.interviewtime').data('time'));
var now = new Date();
```

and [compare those two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170054/compare-two-dates-with-javascript):

```
if (idate.getTime() < now.getTime())
```

---

After that, you need to [fix your selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). `$(this).parent().addClass('dngr');` won't do anything in that function because `this` is not defined.

Possibly you need a loop like this:

```
$('.interviewtime').each(function(i,el) {
    var idate = new Date($('.interviewtime').data('time'));
    var now = new Date();
    if (idate.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('dngr'); // 'this' is the current .interviewtime
    };
});
```

That said, there seems to be no justification for running this code every half-second (500ms). Once a minute should be enough.

Comment: I tried it but doesnt work, i placed an alert in the condition to check if it enters the condition. The alert popped up but the background color didnt change not did it add the class

Comment: Updated answer. You need to define what `this` or narrow down the selector yourself.

Comment: yup. i used both this and idate as selectors but nothing happened.

Comment: `idate` is not a selector string! You need to specifically select an element somewhere on the page; `this` (usually) only makes sense inside an event handler.

Comment: how to select it then?. I have been banging my brains on this for 5hrs if not more. First i used a query inside `$('somequery').parent().addClass('dngr');` but that didnt work either.

Comment: Updated answer again.

Comment: Woo Nice that progress but it added `dngr` all my `divs` even the ones which are scheduled for tomorrow :-(

Comment: Did you want `idate.getTime() > now.getTime()` instead?

Comment: No that didnt work. So i mashedup your code and my code together. All my conditions and date format remain the same only i used your method of selecting the div and it worked. i changed system time too and it responded as it should. But thats only for dngr .

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing dates in that way, you should cast `$('.interviewtime').data('time')` and `moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')` to int before comparing. You can use `parseInt(String)`;

If you don't cast you are comparing Strings and that may be the error.

Also you have an API in momentjs to compare dates:

```
moment().diff(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);
```

Comment: i tried `parseInt($('.interviewtime').data('time')) < parseInt(moment().format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss'))` but still no result @edrian

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$appointment_time = you appointment time stamp
$current_time = current time

$class = '';

if($appointment_time < $current_time)
{
$class = 'dngr'
}
?>
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>"></div>
```

you can apply css classes like this no need to add js

Comment: No No php is childs play i am avoiding this as the user wont refresh the page from time to time. Hence im using jquery

Comment: you can realod your div every min

Comment: i believe you mean ajax. That can be done, but it will ping the server again and again. Unnecessary utilization of resources. The server should be doing other imp stuff