# Error to validate the start date and end date in php file

Tags: javascript

When we declare the java script the validation not applied and not fired an error wile the is same as input type i have declared the code in php file.

I have used `Xammp server`, running `MySQL 5`, `PHP 7.6.2` and `Apache 2`.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    //Validation for Stratdate & Enddate for New Ticket creation form                       

    $("#tedate").change(function () {

        var objFromDate = document.getElementById("tsdate").value; 
        var objToDate = document.getElementById("tedate").value;

        var FromDate = new Date(objFromDate);
        var ToDate = new Date(objToDate);

        if(FromDate > ToDate )
        {
            alert("Due Date Should Be Greater Than Start Date");
            document.getElementById("tedate").value = "";
            return false; 
        }

    });
</script>
```

start date

```
<input type='date' id="tsdate" class="form-control col-md-6"  placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" name="startdate">
```

due date

```
<input type='date' id="tedate" class="form-control col-md-6" placeholder="Enter Due Date" name="enddate" required />
```

I want validate due date is greater than start date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare dates with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170054/compare-dates-with-javascript)

Comment: No this is not my problem

Comment: seems to be working fine for me:- https://jsfiddle.net/74r15xoe/2/

Comment: Yes is working fine i will also try in another file that works and when it call another file is not work i  didn't get where is wrong

Comment: _"Yes is working fine i will also try in another file that works"_? So the posted code works? Then what is your issue? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Yes the code is work but alert not fire the validation cannot apply when it called in another file.

Answer (score 2):

Use strtotime function in php

```
if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2)){
      /* Code */
}
```

Comment: i will execute this in front end

Answer (score 0):

Use getTime() function which will convert the time into epoch format.For more details visit https://www.epochconverter.com/programming/#javascript

you can do the following to check in the frontend.

Javascript

```
  $(".data-controller").change(function () {
        var objFromDate = document.getElementById("tsdate").value;
        var objToDate = document.getElementById("tedate").value;

        var FromDate = (new Date(objFromDate).getTime()) / 1000;
        var ToDate = (new Date(objToDate).getTime()) / 1000;

        if (FromDate > ToDate) {
            alert("Due Date Should Be Greater Than Start Date");
        }

    });
```

HTML

```
<input type='date' id="tsdate" class="form-control col-md-6 data-controller" placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy"
               name="startdate">  // class data-controller added
<input type='date' id="tedate" class="form-control col-md-6 data-controller" placeholder="Enter Due Date"
               name="enddate"
               required/> // class data-controller added
```

Comment: .datacontroller is class or id

Comment: I have added that class. look in the html class attribute. For both input type or you can just use id. your choice. Look in the HTML section code.

Comment: It should work. I had tested the code. Just do copy and paste.

Comment: OK i will check agian

Comment: Give input for both.

Comment: yes is working when it call in another file but when i call in my work file than dont work

Comment: is working is my mistake for same id's will provide for two input tags